# .contains() return false in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

[This code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQEU0RHJ62H9) return false in Internet Explorer. Any alternative?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #myDIV {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="myDIV">
    <p>I am a p element inside div, and I have a <span id="mySPAN">span</span> element inside of me.</p>
  </div>
  <p>I am a p element inside div, and I have a <span id="mySPAN">span</span> element inside</p>


  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var span = document.getElementById("mySPAN");
      var text = span.childNodes[0];
      var div = document.getElementById("myDIV").contains(text);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = div;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to check whether the div element contains the selected range:

```
function getRange(root): Range {
    const sel = window.getSelection();
    const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    if (range && range.commonAncestorContainer !== root && root.contains(range.commonAncestorContainer)) {
        return range.cloneRange();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I want to check whether the div element contains the selected range:

**Current behavior in internet explorer:**
[image: Current behavior in internet explorer:]

Comment: what is your case ?

Comment: You have two `<span id="mySPAN">span</span>` in your code. You should be aware that the IDs should not be repeated.

Comment: I want to check whether the div element contains the selected range:


function getRange(root): Range {
    const sel = window.getSelection();
    const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    if (range && range.commonAncestorContainer !== root && root.contains(range.commonAncestorContainer)) {
        return range.cloneRange();
    }
    return null;
}

Comment: Your code hosted on w3schools and the snippet you shared are not at all related. Why does it matter if the first code returns false if you're not even using it in the second snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need child Node.

Because the `DOM` contains check the full `DOM` not the Node Child. Please try this below function instead of yours. And it is working!

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var span = document.getElementById("mySPAN");
    var div = document.getElementById("myDIV").contains(span);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = div;
}
</script>
```

DEMO: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQFMFOKPLHO3

Comment: If the range.commonAncestorContainer type is not [object Text], your code works!
else if type range.commonAncestorContainer [object Text] your code does not work!